# How to Make a Function Returns Pointer to Array of Function Pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

on this follow program I've tried to make a function that returns a pointer to array of 4 function pointers but I don't know the way how it works and how can I call it and receive the return value also there is an array of 4 function pointers (made it to extract the difference but I Couldn't) now I'm confused of the way that I can call the functions from any 2 of these methods whether array or the Function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

uint32 (*(*Fun2Ptr(void))[4])(void);
uint32 Function_1(void);
uint32 Function_2(void);
uint32 Function_3(void);
uint32 Function_4(void);

uint32(*Arrayof4FP[4])(void) = {Function_1 ,Function_2 ,
                                Function_3 ,Function_4};

int main()
{
    uint32(*(*LocalMainArrof4FP)[4])(void) = Fun2Ptr();
    printf("---------------Array--------------\n");
    printf("%i \n" , (*Arrayof4FP[0])()); // 1
    printf("%i \n" , (*Arrayof4FP[1])()); // 2
    printf("%i \n" , (*Arrayof4FP[2])()); // 3
    printf("%i \n" , (*Arrayof4FP[3])()); // 4
    printf("-----------Using Function-------------\n");
    printf("%i \n" ,(*LocalMainArrof4FP)[0]() ); // 1
    printf("%i \n" ,(*LocalMainArrof4FP)[1]() ); // 2
    printf("%i \n" ,(*LocalMainArrof4FP)[2]() ); // 3
    printf("%i \n" ,(*LocalMainArrof4FP)[3]() ); // 4
    
    return 0;
}
uint32 Function_1(void)
{
    return 1;
}
uint32 Function_2(void)
{
    return 2;
}
uint32 Function_3(void)
{
    return 3;
}
uint32 Function_4(void)
{
    return 4;
}
uint32 (*(*Fun2Ptr(void))[4])(void)
{
    uint32 (*(*LocalPtrs)[4])(void) = &Arrayof4FP;
    return LocalPtrs;
}
```

Comment: To make it much simpler, use type-aliases. Like `typedef uint32 (*funcptr)(void);`. Then you can use it as any other type, like `funcptr* Fun2Ptr(void);` or `funptr Arrayof4FP[] = { ... };`

Comment: Also note that arrays *decay* to pointers to their first element, and that is usually enough to handle arrays. So instead of e.g. `funcptr (*localptrs)[4] = &Arrayof4FP;`, you can just do `funcptr *localptrs = Arrayof4FP; /* Same as &Arrayof4FP[0] */` Then you can just use `localptrs[i]` like any other array.

Comment: You need a `typedef` or include for `uint32`.

Comment: Similarly, functions decay into function pointers, so you can de-reference a function pointer as much as you want, it will only bounce back from function to function pointer again.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return an array from a function instead return a pointer.  Moved the array to the function and ensure liveliness with the `static` keyword.  Added the missing typedef for `uint32`, and used the format macros from inittypes.h to ensure the correct size:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t uint32;

uint32 Function_1(void) {
    return 1;
}

uint32 Function_2(void) {
    return 2;
}

uint32 (**Fun2Ptr(void))(void) {
    static uint32 (*fp[])(void) = { Function_1, Function_2 };
    return fp;
}

int main(void) {
    uint32 (**fp)(void) = Fun2Ptr();
    printf("-----------Using Function-------------\n");
    printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", fp[0]()); // 1
    printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", fp[1]()); // 2
    return 0;
}
```

and resulting output:

```
-----------Using Function-------------
1
2
```